# send_media_group with BytesIO to telegram bot

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, bytesio, aiogram

I'm creating an image with PIL and storing it in the clipboard with BytesIO.I want to send an image album to telegram bot, but I get an error:

Code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
from io import BytesIO
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import logging

API_TOKEN = 'xxxxxx'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

def createimg()
    im = Image.new('RGB', (256, 256), color='black')
    bio = BytesIO()
    bio.name = 'res.png'
    im.save(bio, 'PNG')
    bio.seek(0)
    return bio

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_media_group(message.from_user.id, [createimg(), createimg()])
```

Error:

```
   raise TypeError(f"Media must be an instance of InputMedia or dict, not {type(media).__name__}")
TypeError: Media must be an instance of InputMedia or dict, not BytesIO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use subclasses of [`aiogram.types.InputMedia`](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/input_media.html#inputmedia) objects in your list, not plain `io.BytesIO` objects. In your case it must be `aiogram.types.InputMediaPhoto`, which accepts `aiogram.types.InputFile` object as first argument, where you can put your plain `io.BytesIO` objects directly.

Also, consider using shortcuts in your code as it makes your code cleaner and more readable. For example, you can `.reply()` or `.answer()` to a `aiogram.types.Message`, which is a shortcut for `aiogram.Bot.send_message()`. In your case you should use `aiogram.types.Message.answer_media_group`.

So, your code should be like this:

```
# Some code is omitted in favor of brievity

def wrap_media(bytesio, **kwargs):
    """Wraps plain BytesIO objects into InputMediaPhoto"""
    # First, rewind internal file pointer to the beginning so the contents
    #  can be read by InputFile class
    bytesio.seek(0)
    return types.InputMediaPhoto(types.InputFile(bytesio), **kwargs)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def send_welcome(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer_media_group([wrap_media(createimg()), wrap_media(createimg())])
```

For more info of what `aiogram.types.InputMediaPhoto` accepts, refer to [aiogram documentation](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/input_media.html#inputmediaphoto).